# Want non duplicate elements from list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, duplicates

From following list I need only 'wow' and 'quit'.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();                
list.add("test");       
list.add("test");                   
list.add("wow");    
list.add("quit");
list.add("tree");
list.add("tree");
```

Comment: Do you want to save one "test" and "tree" (aka: remove duplicates) or do you want to remove every occurrence if it has duplicates?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7414753/59087

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identify duplicates in a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414667/identify-duplicates-in-a-list)

Answer (score 8):

you can check the frequency of an element in the Collection and rule out the elements which have frequency higher than 1.

```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("test");       
    list.add("test");                   
    list.add("wow");    
    list.add("quit");
    list.add("tree");
    list.add("tree");
    for(String s: list){
        if(Collections.frequency(list, s) == 1){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Output:

```
wow
quit
```

Comment: Your way is also working fine for i != 1, but I think for i = 1 I would prefer the `indexOf()` way I posted. +1 Anyway ;)

Comment: This and the indexOf implementation both run in O(n^2).  The two hash examples are preferable for any large n.

Answer (score 4):

This snippet should leave you with a set (`output`) which contains only non-duplicated elements of your list.

```
HashSet<String> temp = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> output = new HashSet<String>();

for (String element : list)
{
    if (temp.contains(element)) output.remove(element);
    else
    {
        temp.insert(element);
        output.insert(element);
    }
}
```

Operates in O(n*log(n)) time: one set of logarithmic operations (set lookups, inserts, etc) for each of the n elements in the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use HashMap impl to count occurences and select only onces that occur once.

e.g.

```
void check(List<String> list)
{
  Map<String,Integer> checker = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(String value: list)
  {
    Integer count = checker.get(value); 
    if (count==null)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
    checker.put(value, ++count);
  }
  // now select only values with count == 1
  for(String value: checker.keySet())
  {
    if (checker.get(value) == 1)
    {
      result.add(value);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(result); 
}
```

Comment: `checker.put(value, count++);` should probably be `checker.put(value, ++count);`

Answer (score 2):

And a Third way

```
List result = new ArrayList();
for(Object o : list){
   if(list.indexOf(o) == list.lastIndexOf(o))
   result.add(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java 8 way without streams:

```
Map<String, Long> counts = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(word -> counts.merge(word, 1L, Long::sum));

counts.values().removeIf(count -> count > 1);
```

This first iterates the list and stores the frequency of each word in the `counts` map. For this I'm using the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method, which either associates the provided value (`1L` in this case) with the given key (`word` here) or uses the provided merge function (`Long::sum`) to combine an existent value with the given one.

Then, words with a frequency greater than `1` are removed from the map via the [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.

The whole process has `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8+**

```
list.stream()                                              // Stream
    .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(list, i) == 1)      // Stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList())                          // List
    .forEach(System.out::println);                         // void
```

It prints every element from that list that appears exactly once.

Details:

- [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface
- [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class

Answer (score 1):

@ROMANIA_Engineer's solution should work just fine, but it does hide an O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity in it, since `Collections.frequency` is an O(n) operation.

A more efficient solution that can still be squeezed in to a single statement could be to count how many times each item occurs and filter just items that appear once:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1L)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

List aList = Arrays.asList("test", "test",
"wow", "wow", "wow");

Set hashSet = new HashSet(aList);

hashSet.addAll(aList);

now you can print HashSet all the duplicates values removed

Answer (score 1):

Easily clean a list using a lambda:

```
list.removeIf(element -> Collections.frequency(list, element) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a third-party library, the following can be used with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("test", "test", "wow", "quit", "tree", "tree");

Set<String> set = Bags.mutable.withAll(list).selectUnique();

System.out.println(set);
```

Outputs:

```
[wow, quit]
```

You can also construct a `Bag` directly instead of creating a `List` as follows:

```
MutableBag<String> bag = 
    Bags.mutable.with("test", "test", "wow", "quit", "tree", "tree");

MutableSet<String> set = bag.selectUnique();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 Stream api feature to create different list with only unique elements from original list. Please see below code for reference.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();                
list.add("test");       
list.add("test");                   
list.add("wow");    
list.add("quit");
list.add("tree");
list.add("tree");

List<String> uniqueElements = list.stream().filter(element- 
>Collections.frequency(list,element)==1).toList();
```

Above code will initialize 'uniqueElements' list with unique elements from 'list'.