# Filter List for unique elements

Tags: java, algorithm, list, unique

I am searching for an elegant way to filter a list for only the elements that are unique. An example:

```
   [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4]
-> [3, 4] // 1 and 2 occur more than once
```

Most solutions I found manually compute the occurrences of all elements and then filter by the elements that have exactly one occurrence.

That does not sound too elegant to me, maybe there is a better solution, a best practice or a name for a data-structure that solves this already? I was also thinking about maybe utilizing streams, but I do not know how.

---

Note that I am not asking for duplicate removal, i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` but for keeping only the unique elements, so `[3, 4]`.

The order of the resulting list or what type of `Collection` exactly does not matter to me.

Comment: has your resulting list to keep its order?

Comment: @user753642, nope.

Comment: If you are not constrained to use O(n) extra space then this is elegant solution.
If you can't use extra O(n) space then you can sort the list and then traverse and delete the nodes which have duplicate neighbor node along with the current node. This will be O(nlogn) solution because of sorting but yeah there will always a trade off between space and time and you need to choose one or the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want non duplicate elements from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225302/want-non-duplicate-elements-from-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there is a better approach than actually counting and filtering for the ones that only appeared once. At least, all approaches I can think of will use *something similar* to that under the hood.

Also, it is not clear what you mean by elegant, readability or performance? So I will just dump some approaches.

---

### `Stream` counting

Here is a stream-variant that computes number of occurrences (`Map`) and then filters for elements that appear only once. It is essentially the same as what you described already, or what `Bag`s do under the hood:

```
List<E> result = elements.stream() // Stream<E>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) // Map<E, Long>
    .entries() // Set<Entry<E, Long>>
    .stream()  // Stream<Entry<E, Long>>
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
    .map(Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It requires two full iterations over the data-set. Since it uses the Stream-API, the operations support multi-threading right from the get-go though. So if you have lots of elements, this might be pretty fast due to that.

---

### Manual `Set`

Here is another approach that reduces iteration and lookup time by manually collecting into a `Set` to identify duplicates as fast as possible:

```
Set<E> result = new HashSet<>();
Set<E> appeared = new HashSet<>();

for (E element : elements) {
    if (result.contains(element)) { // 2nd occurrence
        result.remove(element);
        appeared.add(element);
        continue;
    }
    if (appeared.contains(element)) { // >2nd occurrence
        continue;
    }

    result.add(element); // 1st occurrence
}
```

As you see, this only requires one iteration over the `elements` instead of multiple.

This approach is elegant in a sense that it does not compute unnecessary information. For what you want, it is completely irrelevant to compute how often exactly elements appear. We only care for *"does it appear once or more often?"* and not if it appears 5 times or 11 times.

Comment: Your second solution is what I was supposed to post

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bag](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-bag) to count occurrences (`getCount(1)` for unique)

> Bag is a collection that allows storing multiple items along with their repetition count:
>
> ```
> public void whenAdded_thenCountIsKept() {
>    Bag<Integer> bag = new HashBag<>(
>    Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4));         
>    assertThat(2, equalTo(bag.getCount(1)));
> }
> ```

Or `CollectionBag`

> Apache Collections' library provides a decorator called the CollectionBag. We can use this to make our bag collections compliant with the Java Collection contract:

And get [unique set](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html#uniqueSet--):

```
bag.uniqueSet();
```

> Returns a Set of unique elements in the Bag.

Comment: Does `Bag` have a method to fetch all elements within the `Bag` that appear X times? I don't need just the count - I need a collection of the elements.

Comment: @JohnAllison you can use Stream and filter elements with count 1

Comment: While a `Bag` solves this in a few lines, it is essentially what OP described (a `Map` that counts occurrences and then filters for the elements with only one occurrence). Just as a note for OP.

Comment: @or use `uniqueSet` see https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html#uniqueSet--

Comment: @Zabuza `Bag` is Apache collection interface which defers from Java's `Map`

Comment: A `Bag` is a standard data-structure that groups elements by their occurrence. It is much similar to a `Map<Key, List<E>>` or a `Map<E, Long>`. Just saying that it more or less is the same approach under the hood. I do not know OPs exact requirements, maybe this disqualifies it then. Maybe not. Just a note.

Comment: For clarification, I like your answer since a `Bag` is exactly the correct tool for grouping by occurrences. Especially the `uniqueSet()` is really elegant. Most likely the most compact and still readable solution to OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

One need first to collect all, reached the end for deleting groups of more than 1 element.

```
Map<String, Long> map = Stream.of("a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "c")
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                     Collectors.counting()));
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1L)
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or in one go:

```
        Stream.of("a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "c")
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1L)
                .map(e -> e.getKey())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using a map to accumulate frequency counts sounds like a good one: it runs in roughly linear (O(*n*)) time and only requires O(*n*) extra space.

Here's an algorithm that requires ***zero** extra space*, at the expense of running in O(*n^2*) time:

```
public static <T> void retainSingletons(List<T> list)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < list.size()) {
        boolean foundDup = false;
        int j = i + 1;
        while (j < list.size()) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))) {
                list.remove(j);
                foundDup = true;
            } else {
                ++j;
            }
        }
        if (foundDup) {
            list.remove(i);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is straightforward: step a slow pointer, `i`, over the list until it runs off the end; for each value of `i`, run a fast pointer `j` from `i+1` until the end of the list,  removing any `list[j]` that's a duplicate of `list[i]`; after `j` runs out, if any duplicates of `list[i]` were found and removed, also remove `list[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
IntList list = IntLists.mutable.with(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4);
IntSet unique = list.toBag().selectUnique();
System.out.println(unique);
```

Using an `IntList` removes the need to box the `int` values and `Integer` objects.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the correct code below. Implemented in Java by using Stream API and Functional Interfaces.

```
// Code to Print Only Non Duplicate Elements
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NonDuplicateElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7);

        // Use a Predicate to check for duplicates
        Predicate<Integer> isDuplicate = new Predicate<Integer>() {
            Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();

            @Override
            public boolean test(Integer number) {
                return !seen.add(number); // Returns true if number is already seen (duplicate)
            }
        };

        // Filter the list to get duplicate elements
        List<Integer> duplicateNumbers = numbers.stream()
                .filter(isDuplicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Print the non-duplicate elements
        List<Integer> finalResult = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int number : numbers) {
            if (!duplicateNumbers.contains(number)) {
                finalResult.add(number);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(finalResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).