# Custom annotation to validate unique elements

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I need to write custom annotation for UniqueElements. I know Hibernate provides one of these, but I need to validate by just one parameter (so can not use hashCode).

I have something like this:

```
@CustomAnnotatinon
List<MyParameter> parameters;
```

Lets say MyParameter have id, value and type, but I have to validate unique elements only by id. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: do you want `MyParameter` object with duplicated ids to be ignored or do want the validation annoration to give an error?

Comment: If two MyParameter have the same id, exception should be thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have done in a similar situation with [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-errormessage) (don't know if it is the best way) is something like the following:

In your custom annotation add a constraint annotation with a validating class:

```
@Constraint (validatedBy = UniqueIdValidator.class)
public @interface CustomAnnotation
```

Then I have created the UniqueIdValidator class (I used `array` as field instead of `List` like you do, but I hope it works)

```
public class UniqueIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomAnnotation, List<String>>
```

with the method:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(List<String> values, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext)
```

in this method you can check if your `List` contains duplicates and throw an exception or use the error handling features, like adding a message to the `constraintContext` like they do in the link I added above.

To find the duplicates you can do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7414753/3959856) i.e.

Comment: Thanks :) To be hones I got something very similar but was not sure if should I take List as argument or try to get List + last added value to that list.