# How to validate whether month dropdown on Facebook contains any duplicate entries?

Tags: java, list, selenium, collections, set

```
 String[] arr = {"Month","Jan","Feb","Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
 WebElement dropDown = getDriver().findElement(By.id("month"));
 Select select = new Select(dropDown);
 List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();

 for(WebElement we : options){
     for(int i = 1; i<arr.length; i++){
         if(we.getText().equals(arr[i])){
             System.out.println("Matched" );
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

I want to find duplicate months on a Facebook dropdown by using Selenium in Java.

I tried findelement, web element but I could not do that. Right now; I can match the months with the webpage. Original question is like this: find if month dropdown contains any duplicates. If yes then print out those values which are duplicate. Thnx

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the guidelines given on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, provide enough information and the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Why would there be duplicate months in a dropdown?

Comment: You are right. Maybe I could not explain exactly. My professor asked me this question. Original question is like this: find if month dropdown contains any duplicates.if yes then print out those values which are duplicate. My case is Facebook dropdown.Thnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify duplicates in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414667/identify-duplicates-in-a-list)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Can you please help me to understand why this question qualified as **too broad**? OP clearly mentioned s/he _want to find duplicate months_ which Facebook dropdown doesn't have and flatly accepted and conveyed _You are right. Maybe I could not explain exactly. My professor asked me this question_ along with his code trials. Doesn't it qualifies as a legitimate question as a _New contributor_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your *usecase* is to find duplicate months on the Facebook dropdown by using *Selenium* and *Java* you really don't need the reference array. To find if the month dropdown contains any duplicates and print out those values which are duplicate you can use the following solution:

- This code block extracts the *list* of *months* from the dropdown on *Facebook*:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
  WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
  Select select = new Select(dropDown);
  List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
  ArrayList<String> months = new  ArrayList<>();
  for(WebElement we : options)
      months.add(we.getText());
  System.out.println("Current list of months: " +months);
  ```
- For the sake of demonstaration through this code block we will add 3 duplicated entries:

  ```
  months.add("Month");
  months.add("Feb");
  months.add("Dec");
  ```
- In this code block we have created a function to return the *duplicated months*:

  ```
  public static Set<String> findDuplicates(List<String> listContainingDuplicates)
  { 
      final Set<String> setToReturn = new HashSet<>();
      final Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
      for (String myString : listContainingDuplicates)
      {
          if (!set1.add(myString))
              setToReturn.add(myString);
      }
      System.out.println("Unique months: " +set1);
      return setToReturn;
  }
  ```
- Now, you can call the function `findDuplicates()` as follows:

  ```
  System.out.println("Duplicated months: " +findDuplicates(months));
  ```
- So the complete solution will be:

  ```
  package Duplicates;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashSet;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Set;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


  public class Find_Duplicates_In_List {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
          WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
          Select select = new Select(dropDown);
          List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
          ArrayList<String> months = new  ArrayList<>();
          for(WebElement we : options)
          months.add(we.getText());
          System.out.println("Current list of months: " +months);
          months.add("Month");
          months.add("Feb");
          months.add("Dec");
          System.out.println("Duplicated months: " +findDuplicates(months));
      }

      public static Set<String> findDuplicates(List<String> listContainingDuplicates)
      { 
        final Set<String> setToReturn = new HashSet<>();
        final Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        for (String myString : listContainingDuplicates)
        {
         if (!set1.add(myString))
          setToReturn.add(myString);
        }
        System.out.println("Unique months: " +set1);
        return setToReturn;
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Current list of months: [Month, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec]
  Unique months: [Jul, Oct, Feb, Apr, Jun, Dec, May, Month, Sept, Aug, Nov, Jan, Mar]
  Duplicated months: [Month, Feb, Dec]
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works...

Comment: I did mark. thank you for your answer...