# How to remove everything except duplicates from a list?

Tags: list, duplicates

I have a list [ a , b , c , b , d]
I want to remove a c and d, while keeping both of the b's.

How do I do this?

I want my end list to be [ b , b ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify duplicates in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414667/identify-duplicates-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

@Yodrangonface,  this is for Python version:

```py
from collections import Counter

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd']
duplicates = [k for k, v in Counter(lst).items() if v >= 2]
duplicates
```

Output:
['b']

Answer (score 0):

This depend on which programming langage your are using.
For instance in java you could handle it that way:

```
List<String> duplicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        duplicateList.add("Cat");
        duplicateList.add("Dog");
        duplicateList.add("Cat");
        duplicateList.add("cow");
        duplicateList.add("Dog");
        duplicateList.add("Cow");
        duplicateList.add("Goat");

    Set<String> duplicated = duplicateList
            .stream()
            // Grouping by number of occurrences
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.toString(),Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            // Filtering of item with more than one occurrence
            .stream().filter(item->item.getValue()>1)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.getKey(), map -> map.getValue()))
            .keySet();

    System.out.println(duplicated);

    List<String> remaining = duplicateList.stream().filter(item->duplicated.contains(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(remaining);
```

output is:

```
[Cat, Dog]
[Cat, Dog, Cat, Dog]
```